# Cannot create an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'' from its string representation '(Collection)' for the '' property

Tags: asp.net, .net, custom-server-controls

I have created a custom web server control in asp.net. I am trying to render a List of a class in the RenderContents method.

Here is my code:

```
 [DefaultProperty("Items")] 
 [ToolboxData("<{0}:News runat=server></{0}:News>")] 
 public class News : WebControl 
 { 

  [Bindable(true)] 
  [Category("Appearance")] 
  [DefaultValue("")] 
  [Localizable(true)] 
  public List<NewsItem> Items 
  { 
   get 
   { 
    List<NewsItem> items = (List<NewsItem>)(ViewState["Items"] == null ? new List<NewsItem>(): ViewState["Items"]); 
    return items; 
   } 

   set 
   { 
    ViewState["Items"] = value; 
   } 
  } 

  protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) 
  { 
    foreach (var item in Items) 
     item.RenderControl(output); 

  } 
 }
```

First of all, when I drag drop this control onto a page, I can access the Items property from the property window in design-time.

Here's the aspx code of it:

```
<Aram:News ID="News1" runat="server" />
```

After I modify the Items (which appears with the value saying it is a Collection ) I don't see any updates on the design view.

And after I click ok, and starting the debug, I get the error:

```
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[AramWebControls.NewsItem, Custom Web Server Control, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' from its string representation '(Collection)' for the 'Items' property.
```

Now that I look back at the aspx code of my control, it has its Items property set to '(Collection)'.

```
<Aram:News ID="News1" runat="server" Items="(Collection)" />
```

How to solve this? I'm gussing that my control should have the List controls as a content.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does this mean `Items="(Collection)"`? "Collection" string set explicitly or here is some data binding to a property?

Comment: @sll I don't touch the aspx code. I just update the design-time property from the properties window, And I add a couple of items. When I'm finished, it just shows it in that way. And when you click back on the `Items` property from the properties window, you don't see those items added. It is empty all over again. Have you ever designed a custom web control before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem.
First of all, the Items are of type List and that is a collection. It can not be persisted inside the News control tag. So it has to be a part of the content of News control tag. This calls for custom viewstate management.

For details you can first refer to [Web Control Collection Property Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9txe1d4x.aspx)
And then you need to override LoadViewState , SaveViewState and TrackViewState to handle the items. For more info on this one refer to [Server Control Properties Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s70936s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error in the Designer of my ASP.net project. The code builds and runs fine but the Designer shows the following error:

```
Error Creating Control - [ServerControlNameOmitted] Cannot create an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' from its string representation '(Collection)' for the 'CustomProperties' property.
```

I previously had this attribute on the related property in the server control code:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public Dictionary<string, object> customProperties { get; set; }
```

To fix it I changed it to this:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public Dictionary<string, object> customProperties { get; set; }
```

Note that I am not trying to persist customProperties between post backs.